# A question about basis linear space

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

See $\mathbb{R}$ as a linear space over $\mathbb{Q}$. $B\subset\mathbb{R}$ is a basis with positive reals.

Can $B$ be a group where multiplication is standard?

Comment: If $B$ were a basis and a multiplicative group, then $B$ contains no algebraic numbers, as the collection of powers will not be $\mathbb{Q}$ independent.

Comment: @thyde641 agreed, but does every base contain algebraic numbers? I think they're easily avoided.

Answer (score 3):

No.

Suppose it is otherwise. Then we have $\sqrt{2}=\sum_{j=1}^n \alpha_jb_j$ for some $\alpha_j\in {\bf Q}\setminus\{0\},b_j\in B$ with $0<\lvert b_1\rvert<\ldots<\lvert b_n\rvert$. Then also
$$2=\left(\sum_{j=1}^n \alpha_jb_j\right)^2=\sum_{i,j}\alpha_i\alpha_jb_ib_j$$
and similarly
$$4=\sum_{i,j,k,l}\alpha_i\alpha_j\alpha_k\alpha_lb_ib_jb_kb_l$$
Summing things up, we get that
$$0=\sum_{i,j,k,l}\alpha_i\alpha_j\alpha_k\alpha_lb_ib_jb_kb_l-\sum_{i,j=1}2\alpha_i\alpha_jb_ib_j$$
Now we have the following facts:

1. If $\lvert b_n\rvert>1$, then the coefficient by $b_n^4$ is $\alpha_n^4$, but it must be zero, which is a contradiction (because $b_n^4$ is the largest element of $B$ in the expression on right hand side).
2. If $\lvert b_1\rvert<1$, then likewise the coefficient of $b_1^4$ is $\alpha_1^4$, again yielding a contradiction.
3. Therefore, we must have $\lvert b_1\rvert=\lvert b_n\rvert=1$, so $n=1$ and $\sqrt 2$ is a rational number, which is a contradiction, so we're done.